# Can a Jordan curve contain measure-theoretic interior points of the domain it bounds?

Tags: measure-theory, plane-curves, geometric-measure-theory

Let $I$ be an interval, and $\gamma:I\to \mathbb{R}^2$ a Jordan curve. By the [Jordan--Schoenflies Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) $\gamma(I)$ splits up $\mathbb{R}^2$ in two connected pieces, that is, $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \gamma(I)$ is made by exactly two connected components, a bounded one, $V$, and an unbounded one $U$, that have as boundary the image of the curve $\gamma(I)$. The bounded one is homeomorphic to the unit disk.

I know that are bad-behaved curves, à la Knopp--Osgood, such that their image has Hausdorff dimension $2$ (if you prefer, a slightly stronger thing is to say it has positive $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure).

I am wondering whether I can tell something on the measure-theoretic interior on $V$, denoted by $V^{(1)}$. We say that a point $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$ belongs to $V^{(1)}$ if
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{|B_r(p)\cap V|}{\pi r^2} = 1.$$

1. Can $\gamma(I)$ contain any point that belongs to the measure-theoretic interior of $V$?

Yes: any curve with an "inner cusp" will do.

2. Can the set of these points have positive ${H}^1$-measure?
3. If yes, is this still true if I exclude the curve from being a Knopp--Osgood one?

Comment: What exactly is $V$? The word "splits" is unclear. Is $V$ the closure of the bounded component of the complement to $\gamma(I)$?

Comment: By J--S Theorem, $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \gamma(I)$ is made of two connected components, a bounded one and an unbounded one. I am denoting by $V$ the bounded one.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: You asked 3 questions (or 4?). The first and third have easy positive answer. I do not know about the second.

Comment: For that it is enough to take any curve with an "inner cusp". What I am really interested in is how many can these points be?

Comment: Yes, indeed, but then your question is very unclearly formulated.